# ¿En la metodología AUP existen historias de usuario?

Tags: metodología

En [*AUP (Proceso Unificado Ágil)*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_Unified_Process) se menciona que solo existe el requerimiento funcional. ¿Un requerimiento funcional es igual a una historia de usuario?

Comment: la historia de usuario puede ser el comportamiento del mismo; o las practicas comunes malas o buenas; es importante tenerlas en cuenta al momento de desarrollar es por ello que puede ser consideradas como un requisito para desarrollo o mas bien debes desarrollar tomándolas en cuenta, lo importante es hacer algo genérico y que tome en consideración el peor escenario del usuario y volvemos a caer en la historia de usuario.

Comment: @hubman, este tipo de preguntas regularmente son cerradas, deberías revisar nuevamente [ask], si buscas opiniones, en el [chat] puedes encontrar opinion de desarrolladores que actualmente trabajan o han trabajado con metodologías Agile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Un requerimiento funcional no es igual a una historia de usuario?

La respuesta es no, no es lo mismo.

Una historia de usuario pertenece a metodologías ágiles, donde solo se aporta el valor de la definición al usuario, digamos que es un tanto más general.

Un requerimiento funcional está orientado a la administración de proyectos clásica o comúnmente conocida como cascada. Un requerimiento o requisito funcional es más a detalle, donde se deben especificar entradas, salidas, comportamiento esperado, componentes involucrados y modificados, implementación etc.

---

¿Pueden trabajar en conjunto una historia de usuario con un requerimiento funcional?

Considero que sí, digamos que el problema puede ser tan amplio como lo desees ver. Una historia de usuario puede tener consigo misma documentación complementaria que involucre el detalle técnico de lo que se pretende con esa historia. No está peleado trabajar los mismos requerimientos en diferentes metodologías, no obstante, no es la mejor práctica y se perderían diferentes ventajas como la de ser un desarrollo "ágil".

Answer (score 2):

Historia de usuario y Requisito Funcional son conceptos diferentes, las historias de usuario tienen algunos aspectos que las hacen diferente de lo que es un requisito, las historias de usuario no deben tener el nivel de detalle que tiene una especificación de requisito, las historias de usuario son cortas, de fácil memorización, siendo algunas veces imposible que una historia de usuario tenga toda la información necesaria para desarrollar, no tienen nada relacionado a pruebas, normativas, ni detalles para codificar, mientras que la especificación de un requisito funcional si tendría dicha información.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno. Tómalo de la siguiente manera. Un requerimiento funcional es la parte real y comprensible de toda la historia de un usuario. Como sabrás la historia puede estar lleno de engaños o de información innecesaria pero el requerimiento funcional es la parte que realmente es entendible y relevante de toda la historia.